# HTTP works in web but not working in actual android device ( IONIC mobile development )

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

> **Problem:** my ngfor works perfecty on running web, but when ı emulate my app on real device, its just not working. ı looked all over
>   the internet for solution but couldnt find, just as a close one(thats
>   what ı think), some says this is ngZone issue, and ı dont have any
>   idea what is it.

my service

```
getMenuObject(): Observable<any> {

    return this.http
      .post("xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx",{ HotelId:25, GroupId:9 });
  }
```

my .ts

```
data: Array<any>=[]

ngOnInit(){
 this.httpService.getMenuObject().toPromise().then(x=>{
      this.data = x;
      console.log(this.data)
      if(x.IsGroup==true){
          this.splashScreen.hide();

       } else{
         this.router.navigate(['folder/Inbox']);
       }
    });
}
```

my html:

```
<ion-card  *ngFor="let otel of data.MobileHotelDefinitions" style="margin: 40px 0;border-radius: 0;">
        <ion-card-header style="padding: 0;">
          <ion-img (click)="goToHotel()" [src]="otel.MobileApplicationDefinition.GroupImageUrl"></ion-img>
          <div class="otelName">
            <div style="flex: 1;">{{otel.Name}}</div>
            <div style="color: goldenrod;">★★★★★</div>
          </div>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
          Keep close to Nature's heart... and break clear away, once in awhile,
          and climb a mountain or spend a week in the woods. Wash your spirit clean.
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
```

my console:
[image]

my app on web browser (ionic serve --o):

[image]

my app on real android device (huawei android 9):
[image]

Comment: Try wrapping your code with NgZone and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My problem was I was trying to use httpClient(angular one), but on mobile you need ionic http, So There are 2 http:**

1. import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx'; //for mobile http
   requests you have to use this ([you can install it from here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http))
2. import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http"; //for browser
   development you have to use this.

And it was hard to implement the correct http way for mobile, to help you I leave an example mobile http request here. (to prevent having couple of http errors)

**My Service.ts**

```
 constructor(private http:HTTP, private httpWEB: HttpClient) {

    this.http.setHeader('*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
    this.http.setHeader('*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
    this.http.setHeader('*', 'Accept','application/json');
    this.http.setHeader('*', 'content-type','application/json');
    this.http.setDataSerializer('json');
  }

  post(url:string,body:any):Promise<any>{    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.setDataSerializer('json');
      this.http.post(url, body, {}).then(res =>{
        resolve(JSON.parse(res.data));
      })
      .catch(err =>{
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

**in Config.xlm update this section to prevent clearTextTraffic error for http request**

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
```

**And also update your network_securty_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">testapi.xxx.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The `data` variable isn't the array. The `MobileHotelDefinitions` property inside it is the array. So it's better to define it's type as `any` instead of `Array`.
2. Is there any specific need for converting the HTTP observable to a promise? Try to directly use the observable.
3. Include a `*ngIf` check in the template before using the properties.
4. Notice the use of [safe navigation operator `?.`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) in the template. It checks if the parent property is defined before trying to access it's child properties.

Controller

```js
data: any;    // <-- `any` here

ngOnInit() {
  this.httpService.getMenuObject().subscribe(
    response => {
      this.data = response;
      console.log(this.data);
      if (response.IsGroup == true) {
        this.splashScreen.hide();
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['folder/Inbox']);
      }
    },
    error => {
      // always good practice to handle HTTP errors
    }
  );
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="data">     <!-- check here -->
  <ion-card  *ngFor="let otel of data.MobileHotelDefinitions" style="margin: 40px 0;border-radius: 0;">
    <ion-card-header style="padding: 0;">
      <ion-img (click)="goToHotel()" [src]="otel?.MobileApplicationDefinition?.GroupImageUrl"></ion-img>
      <div class="otelName">
        <div style="flex: 1;">{{otel?.Name}}</div>
        <div style="color: goldenrod;">★★★★★</div>
      </div>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Keep close to Nature's heart... and break clear away, once in awhile,
      and climb a mountain or spend a week in the woods. Wash your spirit clean.
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ng-container>
```

If the issue still persists then the variable update is outside the Angular Zone. Try to wrap the call in [`NgZone.run()`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run) function to run the statement within the Angular zone.

```js
import { Component, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;

  constructor(private zone:NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpService.getMenuObject().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.zone.run(() => this.data = response);    // <-- assign the value within Angular zone and trigger change detection
        console.log(this.data)
        if (response.IsGroup == true) {
          this.splashScreen.hide();
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['folder/Inbox']);
        }
      },
      error => {
        // always good practice to handle HTTP errors
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: I am so sorry to say that none of above worked.. You explaned everything so good, at least thank you so much for that.. this problem is really interesting isnt it..

Comment: @WorldOfEmre: That is unfortunate. Could you check if the backend sends the correct response? Try to do something obvious in the error callback, like redirecting to some other route. That way we can be sure the backend does send the data correctly in the mobile device.